# Issues in searching the data in kibana

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch, nested, kibana

Issues in searching the data in kibana. It is not working as expected. The situation is

1. The kind of logs which are collected are firewall logs
2. There are 2 fields Action and matches.action
3. Action specifies the end action taken by firewall and matches.action specifies the preliminary action taken. The values can be either one or more of (log, allow, drop, challenge, simulate)
4. Since I dont want 2 fields for the same kind of data. I merged matches.action to action which makes the field action an array.
5. When I'm filtering for a data it is showing what else is not required is also shown.

Eg: when searching for "drop" traffic it is showing "simulate" traffic also as well.
Refer the the image below

[Kibana map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8Uyv.png)

The data is stored in es like this in an array.
[Discover tab of kibana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9Plk.png)

Regards

Karthik.K

Comment: can you please share the mapping and sample document

Comment: I got it clarified from the elastic forums that I need to use Nested data type. But in my case its not gonna help as Kibana is yet to provide visualization support for Nested data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it clarified from the elastic forums that I need to use Nested data type. But in my case its not gonna help as Kibana is yet to provide visualization support for Nested data type

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/issues-with-searching-data-in-array/204420/4